# E-mails sent to @icloud.com deleted before receiving and sender not notified

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email

I am thinking of making my iCloud e-mail address my primary one. However, I came across the two articles linked below, which seem to suggest iCloud is actually deleting e-mails when they don't meet their criteria **before delivering them to any of the mailboxes** (Inbox, Junk mail, etc.). The worst thing is the sender of the e-mail isn't even notified about the failed delivery. I want to know if this is actually true. Did anyone experience this too? Is there a workaround?

https://www.cultofmac.com/217557/apples-deleting-icloud-emails-that-contain-the-phrase-barely-legal-teens/
https://michaelkummer.com/tech/apple-junk-mail-filter/

Thank you

Comment: What did you send and what did not arrive?

Comment: Nothing yet. As I wrote "I am thinking of making my iCloud e-mail address my primary one..." - the reason for my question is that I don't want to deal with such an issue in the first place. I don't want ANY e-mail directed to me to be lost.

Comment: Starts with "E-mails sent to @icloud.com deleted before receiving and sender not notified" so question clearly states you lost them....

Comment: I just tested with the example mentioned in the Cult Of Mac post, the mail got delivered to @me.com. But the simple answer probably is: If you want to have full control over your mail server, don't rely on {Apple,Google,Microsoft,Yahoo}, set up your own instead.